# ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED never called

Tags: android, bluetooth

I registered a broadcast receiver to receive notifications about Bluetooth states.

One of the actions I  registered for is `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` and `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` but I do not receive any notifications from them.

I referred to posts on this site, and I added the required permissions but still when I connect or disconnect to a CLASSIC devices I do not receive any notification.

Please let me know why I am not receiving any notifications from them.

**update**:

I am using API 19

**code**:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String action = intent.getAction();

    switch (action) {
    case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND"));
        this.mBTNotiObserver.onActionFound((BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE));

        break;

    case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED"));
        break;

    case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED"));
        break;
```

Comment: Define _classic_ device? What API level are they running? According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` was not added until API level 5

Comment: @EdGeorge i am using API 19